# How Ssimple is Thisss?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

Read following passage...

---

`Beginning sstory:`
`There wass a ssound.`
`Maybe a ssnake?`
`It went hissss!`
`Everyone got sscared!`
`Air mattress sstarted leaking.`
`Lord help uss!!!!`

---

... now tell me how many times my favorite letter of the alphabet appears in it.

Comment: `mattress` not `matressss` hmm.

Comment: I've updated my answer, could you provide feedback? I'm actively looking for this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a puzzle but just an exercise in counting letters (and finding hidden ones).

Comment: @Randal'Thor I don't actually understand how this one can call this off topic. You've called it not a puzzle, then parenthesized finding hidden things as if that isn't a puzzle-type endeavor.  [tag:steganography], [tag:word-search], [tag:number-sequence], [tag:word-property], [tag:letter-sequence], [tag:word-sequence] and [tag:minesweeper] are all legitimate tags that have people finding hidden things. The counting part is merely a mechanism to enigmatically show puzzlers that something is indeed hidden.

Comment: @Chowzen Well yeah, but in something like [tag:steganography] or [tag:word-property] there's actually a *puzzle* to be solved. This is simply "count some S's, and spot where I've hidden one", which doesn't really seem like a puzzle to me. Several of the other answers here seem equally valid, which is also a reason to close.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your favorite letter is

> s

And it appears

> 21 times. 20 times as an actual letter, and then, if you Ctrl+F for 's', you find one more hidden:
>  [image: Hidden S]

Comment: Six hundred and seventy two times on the page (at 1440 CST, 8/31/2018).

Comment: I can't find that hidden one, is it in the actual post?

Comment: @Seraphina check out the pattern the yellow-highlighted letters make in the answer's image, and the question when `Ctrl+F`ing for `s`.

Comment: Nicely done! It warms the cockles of my heart to see a new contributor's unique perspective paying off. Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Answer (score 19):

Going back to old chestunts, Your favorite letter

> appears exactly once in the alphabet.
>  Regardless of which letter is your favorite, letters are listed only once in an  alphabet.

Comment: Though the post asks *of the alphabet* not *in the alphabet*; good answer though. I think this meets El-Guest's *cheater-pants-you-can't-do-that* criteria! :D +1

Comment: I just noticed that the M in the third line is bolded.  MIght that be the hint we're missing?

Comment: @PerpetualJ but the "it" in "appears in it" can refer to both the passage and the alphabet.

Comment: I'm not so sure it could refer back to the alphabet itself with that statement. With lateral-thinking, sure! The literal flow of the sentence however refers to the passage. This was still a good answer.

Answer (score 13):

Your favorite letter is the letter

> [ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)

This letter

> is mostly used in the German language; and it stands for a 'double s'. However, the letter ß doesn't belong in the regular alphabet. But it looks like a B so maybe your favorite letter is the letter B? The letter B only appears once in your story; the first letter. Lateral thinking! .. maybe?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not ssure if I've found what you are looking for, but doess your favorite letter appear

> two timess - that'ss if it'ss W.     Thanks to El-Guesst for counting to two (I couldn't).

Because this sstory contains many occurrencess of

> double s, you like doubles cluing double u (W), and there are 2U's so it's a W (doubles) story.

Comment: Doesn't this appear twice? (or are you talking about an actual r13(cnve bs H'f)?

Comment: @El-Guest thank you - you're right - doh. I guess I still haven't found what Chowzen's looking for. I may update (if not delete).

Comment: Tom, it's a good answer, although I'm not sure why the tag is pattern and nothing else

Comment: El-Guest another good point - this post would be more wordplay, even lateral.

Comment: I think every answer so far fits one of those two tags instead of pattern (including mine), to be honest. Alsso, you're sso uuelcome :D

Comment: It's not wordplay. I added the tag "lateral-thinking."

Comment: @Chowzen is anyone here on the right track with their answer so far?

Comment: @El-Guest I'd say the answer that deserves more attention is [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71125/how-ssimple-is-thisss/71135#71135).

Answer (score 4):

If your favourite letter is:

> anything except "I" or "T" (like the implied "S")
>  then 0
>  else 1
>
>  ...because:
>  -- how many times my favorite letter of the alphabet appears in "it"

Comment: I did wonder if someone was going to inquire about that old chestnut, but that's not *it*.

Answer (score 4):

My Observation:

> since there is a pattern tag, i noticed the number of s in each line follows this pattern 2,4,2,4,2 ... maybe this has something to do with the answer we are looking for.

Comment: So, the answer is 42, the answer to everything?

Answer (score 4):

I see that

> You add one 's' for every correct occurrence of 's' in the words. Except for in 'mattress'. So maybe your favourite letter is 'e'? So when writing mattress, you saw 'e' and got distracted and forgot to add (or overcame your problem of adding) the extra 's'. :P 'e' appears 9 times in the text

Comment: This is an interesting answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

> THe letter that appears the most in the passage is `s`. So this must be your favorite. It appears 20 times.
>  
>  Bonus: Your second favorite is `e`. 14 times.

Comment: That's not the number I got...

Answer (score 1):

If the answer is not Marius', and there's no lateral-thinking involved, then perhaps the answer is instead

> 21? As Marius correctly notes, there are 20 S's in the puzzle, but there are also punctuation marks. In fact there is a period, an exclamation mark, and a que**s**tion mark. The **s** in question mark could be the 21st S.

The more I write this answer, the more I feel that the more likely answer is instead

> 22. Question mark is correct, but you would probably pronounce it *que**ss**tion mark* instead to follow the speech ***pattern*** of the rest of the story!

The other old chestnut outside of Jonathan Allen's is of course

> that the phrase "my favorite letter of the alphabet" does not appear at all in the passage.

Comment: But why would you pronounce the punctuation?  It's not like you pronounce each individual letter.

Comment: So then why would it matter if there were 4 S's or 2? It still makes the same sound.

Comment: That's the thing, it wouldn't make a sound unless you pronounce the punctuation.  Normally, it just creates an inflection at the end of the sentence

Comment: I'm saying that there are 4 S's in some words and 2 S's in others for a reason. The lateral-thinking tag means you can't just go and add up all of the S's; the solution is more clever than that. The method that I was proposing is entirely lateral-thinking, since it considers both words _and punctuation marks_ as simple text. Since there's no green checkmark here, it's not the correct solution, but it was my attempt at discovering Chowzen's sneaky trick!

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box, your favourite letter is

> i - Counting the exclamation marks as upside down i's, you get a total of 12!

Alternatively:

> Thanks to @Shahriar Mahmud Sajid for spotting the 2424242 pattern!
>  Using the repeating part (24), we can conclude that your favourite letter is the 24th letter of the alphabet, X, which occurs 0 times sadly.

Answer (score 0):

**The Pattern**: Given by [Shahriar's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71125/how-ssimple-is-thisss/71135#71135), a pattern was found on the occurrences for the letter **s**.

> A pattern of 2, 4, 2, 4, 2 in which each line follows this pattern for the number of instances in which the letter **s** appears.

**The Double Standard**: [Tom's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71125/how-ssimple-is-thisss/71138#71138) sums it up well.

> Double s, you like doubles cluing double u (W), and there are 2U's so it's a W (doubles) story.

**My Answer**: I believe there is more to this than Tom and Shahriar have pointed out.

> I believe your favorite letter is **w** and it occurs **2** times.

**My Reasoning**: There are a lot of things that add up to this, to include the answers that Tom and Shahriar gave. To top it off:

> If you concatenate these numbers together, you get the number **24** which is representative of the letter **w** in the alphabet and it appears **2** times.
>  
>  
>  Also, following the pattern, there are two instances of **w** and they are both on lines where there are four instances of **s**.
>  
>  
>  Also, I would like to point out that the first occurrence of the letter **w** is also positioned at index **24** (1 based, including spaces and punctuation) within the passage; which, is either sheer coincidence, or pure genius.

Answer (score -2):

"Body must be at least 30 characters, you entered 5."  The system lies!

Since

> you don't ask us what your favorite letter is, it's not part of the puzzle and since you don't tell us, the answer is either zero or "not enough information".

Answer (score -3):

Your favorite letter is

> "z".  It appears zero times.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Firstly, could you explain why you believe this is the correct answer? Answers without explanation are likely to end up getting downvoted and/or deleted. Secondly, please remember to hide your answers inside spoiler tags, so as to avoid potentially spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves.

Comment: Other letters appear zero times